# How to get an array of specific "key" in multidimensional array without looping

Tags: php

Let's assume I have the following multidimensional array (retrieved from MySQL or a service):

```
array(
    array(
        [id] => xxx,
        [name] => blah
    ),
    array(
        [id] => yyy,
        [name] => blahblah
    ),
    array(
        [id] => zzz,
        [name] => blahblahblah
    ),
)
```

Can we get an array of `id`s in one "*built-in*" php function call? or one line of code?
I am aware of the traditional looping and getting the value but I don't need this:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $ids[] = $user['id'];
}
print_r($ids);
```

Maybe some `array_map()` and `call_user_func_array()` can do the magic.

Comment: "Can we get an array of ids in one function call?" yes, but you'll have to write the function : )

Comment: @BorisGuéry, I meant *built-in* functions :-)

Comment: P.S: I'm aware I can write `foreach($users as $user) {$ids[] = $user['id'];}` in one line! but you know what I mean/need :-)

Comment: @Eugene, I need the array for other things obviously. And again, this is only for fun and learning new shorthands in PHP.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Since PHP 5.5, you can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$ids = array_column($users, 'id');
```

This is the preferred option on any modern project. However, if you must support PHP<5.5, the following alternatives exist:

Since PHP 5.3, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with an anonymous function, like this:

```
$ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['id'];}, $users);
```

Before <sup><sub>(Technically PHP 4.0.6+)</sub></sup>, you must create an anonymous function with [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) instead:

```
$ids = array_map(create_function('$ar', 'return $ar["id"];'), $users);
```

Comment: nice, now if there's a native function that is similar to `function ($ar) {return $ar['id'];}` return value of key that would be awesome! :-)

Comment: well, that's not a "all in one" function, but Closure (Anynonymous functions) are a very powerfull concept that may be used for such processing, you'll rather like to know how to use them.

Comment: What if I want to get the key too?
Suppose :
$arr = [
  'ball'=>[
    'basket'=>5
  ]
];

I want to get : $ball = ['ball'=>5];

Comment: @Angger Then you have a different question than this one. Feel free to [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as long as you mention in detail what behavior you expect, for instance what should result if the input is `['ball' => ['golf' => 7, 'basket' => 5, 'soccer' => 6], 'shuttle' => ['badminton' => 1]]`.

Comment: Since PHP7.4 you can use `array_map` with an arrow function: `$ids = array_map(fn ($ar) => $ar['id'], $users);`

Comment: Would you mind updating the answer with PHP 7.4 version (arrow functions) and adding a warning about deprecated `create_function()`?

Comment: @Dharman You should pick the first option that is an option. Therefore, there is no need to use arrow functions – In php 7.4 you can just use `array_columns`. I edited in a note saying as much.

Answer (score 16):

#### PHP 5.5+

Starting PHP5.5+ you have [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column) available to you, which makes all of the below obsolete.

#### PHP 5.3+

`$ids = array_map(function ($ar) {return $ar['id'];}, $users);`

Solution by @phihag will work flawlessly in PHP starting from PHP 5.3.0, if you 
need support before that, you will need to copy that wp_list_pluck.

#### PHP < 5.3

Wordpress 3.1+

In Wordpress there is a function called [wp_list_pluck](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)
If you're using Wordpress that solves your problem.

PHP < 5.3

**If you're not using Wordpress**, since the code is open source you can copy paste the code in your project (and rename the function to something you prefer, like array_pick). [View source here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/functions.php#L0)

Answer (score 2):

If `id` is the first key in the array, this'll do:

```
$ids = array_map('current', $users);
```

You should not necessarily rely on this though. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `array_reduce()` if you prefer a more functional approach

For instance:

```
$userNames = array_reduce($users, function ($carry, $user) {
    array_push($carry, $user['name']);
    return $carry;
}, []);
```

Or if you like to be fancy,

```
$userNames = [];
array_map(function ($user) use (&$userNames){
    $userNames[]=$user['name'];
}, $users);
```

This and all the methods above do loop behind the scenes though ;)

Comment: Your first example will not return an array, just the last value found for $user['name'] in the array.  You need to push/append to the $carry and return the $carry as you go.