# PHP function to get needed values form array

Tags: php, arrays

```
function transformArray($array, $key)
{
  $transformed = [];
  foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
   $transformed[] = $value[$key]
 }
 return $transformed;
}

$array = [
0 => [
'key' => 1,
'key2' => 2
]
];

transformArray($array, 'key2');
```

Often I need function to build array from multidimesions array, for that I'm write function like in example, some frameworks have own function  to do this, maybe for this solution exist shortest way with standart `PHP` functions ?

Comment: There is a typo in `$tranasformed = [];`

Comment: @Tuesdave thanks I'm edit.

Comment: $transformed[] = $value[$key] .... is this a typo ???

Comment: Missing semicolon(`;`) in `$transformed[] = $value[$key]`. From where you're getting this `$key`?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul $key is a method param

Comment: Guys this is only exampleto show what I want to shortcut.

Comment: Oh, totally missed that. :P

Comment: **td;lr:** *you are looking for the best method to flatten a multidimensional array*

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping)

Comment: @Wizard, I looked at your latest edit: you made it worse. The spelling should be the same for all occurrences of the variable. BTW, the English spelling is *transformed*. You can do it otherwise of course, but then do it consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to `array_column` function (supported since PHP 5.5).
 It returns the values from a single column in the input multi-dimensional array.
Example from official documentation:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name');
print_r($first_names);
```

---

```
// output:
        Array
    (
        [0] => John
        [1] => Sally
        [2] => Jane
        [3] => Peter
    )
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php