# Show all multidimensional array keys without their values?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, dump

I am working with multidimensional arrays and i need dumping they keys. But their values are wery huge. Is there some easy and quick way dump keys like `print_r` or `var_dump` but without values? Or truncated values?

Own function or 'helper' i can write by myself i want know whether exist some default function which one knows...

Comment: _Is there some easy and quick way dump keys(..)?_ No

Comment: `print_r(array_keys($array))`…?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
 print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Comment: This shows only first level of keys... i wrote multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

What about array_walk_recursive?

```
 array_walk_recursive($mutliDimArray, function($v, $key){       
    echo "<br/> key: ".$key."    val: ".$v;     
 });
```