# Convert PDO fetch in PHP array list

Tags: php, pdo

There are any way to convert a PDO fetch (only 1 column) in a PHP array? Instead of a foreach loop.
Example:

```
"data": [
    {
        "A": "1"
    },
    {
        "A": "2"
    },
    {
        "A": "3"
    }
]
```

expected:

```
"data": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
]
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: `$string['data'] = array_column($string->data,'A');` OR `$string['data'] = array_column($string['data'],'A');`

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank! It's work!

Comment: @AlivetoDie I've tried the second one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array of specific "key" in multidimensional array without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping)

Comment: You can and should get it using fetchAll() with  [PDO::FETCH_COLUMN fetch mode](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_COLUMN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) like eblow:-

```
$string['data'] = array_column($string['data'],'A');
```