# How to get value by key from multidimensional array from an object attribute as number in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to get value by key from the multidimensional array in PHP

We Get TradeID in foreach loop

We get TradeID by Loop one by one

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 1
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [TradeID] => 15950315
                        [Price] => 0.00000170
                        [Type] => buy
                        [Amount] => 712.85989430
                        [Total] => 0.00121368
                        [Time] => 1535337908
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [TradeID] => 15908375
                        [Price] => 0.00000300
                        [Type] => buy
                        [Amount] => 574.71264368
                        [Total] => 0.00172673
                        [Time] => 1535022882
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array of specific "key" in multidimensional array without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping)

Comment: array_column('TradeID') return array of TradeID

Comment: @HabibQadoos, I think it might be a duplicate, but not of that one. This one is an object probably result of a **json_decode()**, it's not an array initially and, therefore, the way to access the array is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use foreach twice.

**PHP Code:**

```
/* Generating structure */
$rawdata = array(
        '',
        1,
        array(
            array(
                'TradeID' => 15950315,
                'Price' => 0.00000170,
                'Type' => 'buy',
                'Amount' => 712.85989430,
                'Total' => 0.00121368,
                'Time' => 1535337908,
            ),
            array(
                'TradeID' => 15908375,
                'Price' => 0.00000300,
                'Type' => 'buy',
                'Amount' => 574.71264368,
                'Total' => 0.00172673,
                'Time' => 1535022882,
            )
        )
    );
$data = (object)$rawdata;
print_r($data);// same output as shown in the question


/** Getting TradeID */

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $tradeKey => $tradevalue) {
            echo $tradevalue['TradeID'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Please check output at: https://3v4l.org/d3KbN

Answer (score -1):

Considering the `$object` variable would be the object you see, and only the first layer is an object, you can cast to an array using the notation `(array)` and continue the logic that you probably know already:

```
$array = (array) $object;

foreach ($array['2'] as $item) {
    echo $item['TradeID'];
}
```

Sorry for the previous answer, this one is fixed and tested here: https://3v4l.org/LOYtp