# PHP - Execute function on an array value

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "time" => 7780
    "name" => "John A. Doe"
    "photo" => "johndoe.png"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "time" => 49800
    "name" => "Jane B. Doe"
    "photo" => "janedoe.png"
  ]
]
```

the `time` value is seconds, my question is how can i loop through the array so that I can run a function like:

`"time" => $this->secondsToHumanReadable(49800)`

My function `secondsToHumanReadable` is tested and working fine, i just want it to insert on the `time` value inside my array result.

**UPDATE:**

Desired output will be:

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "time" => '2 days, 1 hour, 3 minutes, 45 seconds'
        "name" => "John A. Doe"
        "photo" => "johndoe.png"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "time" => '3 hour, 15 minutes, 20 seconds'
        "name" => "Jane B. Doe"
        "photo" => "janedoe.png"
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: With a `foreach`, no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array of specific "key" in multidimensional array without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping)

Comment: @Martijn, I don't think that is a duplicate because the OP wants a loop.

Comment: @kapitan Do you want to modify the original array, or produce a new one?

Comment: @programmer-man - thank you for asking, my question was updated. my answer to your question is either, i just want the easiest solution for this. anyways, someone already gave the answer below. thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```php
$new_array = array_map(function($item) use ($this) {
  $item['time'] = $this->secondsToHumanReadable($item['time']);
  return $item;
}, $my_array);
```

Benefit of using `array_map()` is that the returned array is a new array, so you don't mutate your initial array. It's usually a good practice not to mutate data structures

Comment: my bad, I missed a dollar sign. Try again

Comment: ill try this, ill be back in a sec

Comment: @Ianis - No need of `use` because `$item` references the current looped element of the second paramter `$my_array`.

Comment: @iArcadia if used inside of a class yes, my bad

Comment: @Ianis - Nope, that's me. I read `$item` instead of `$this` in your deleted comment. You may have correct!

Comment: it worked! i just removed the `use ($this)` as suggested by iArcadia, thanks @christopher!!!

Comment: Glad it worked! don't forget to mark it as the accepted answers so other users can benefit too! :)

Comment: I suggest renaming the key so something like 'humantime'. That way, you keep your original value, which you might need later on (maybe not at this point at time, but *at some point*).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foreach`, as @u_mulder said.

```php
// Copying the original array
$result = $array;

foreach($result as $item) {
    $item["time"] = $this->secondsToHumanReadable($item["time"]);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This will mutate the `$array` array. It's usually a good practice to work with immutable values.

Comment: `$item in $array` is __not__ php syntax.

Comment: foreach syntax is : foreach($list as $key => $item) 
$key can be omitted but if you want to change the original array you shoud use $list[$key]

Comment: And updated code will work with copy of array and will __not update__ original array.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco, I agree about the immutability. Updated the code, to let the `foreach` as an option for other people

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foreach` but with [references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
$data = [
  [
    'time' => time()
  ],

  [
    'time' => time() - 5000
  ]
];

foreach ($data as &$datum) {  
  $datum['time'] = date('d/m/Y', $datum['time']);
}

print_r($data);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 27/03/2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 27/03/2019
        )

)
```

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/OtherReflectingOs)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
array(
  "time" => function($foo){return $foo;},
    "name" => "John A. Doe",
    "photo" => "johndoe.png"
);
```

Comment: This part of the question is just a representation of the expected result, not actually php code.

Comment: I just meant that you can denote the function in the array.