# target a subarray using a variable and move it to the top of main array

Tags: php, arrays

two-dimensional array
need to target the subarray where  key `id` is equal to a variable `$id`
and move that target array at the top of main array

```
$id = 2;

$rows = Array(
[0] => Array(
[id] => 1 [0] => 1
[top] => vid [1] => vid)

// target array
[1] => Array(
[id] => 2 [0] => 2 // target element
[top] => img [1] => img)

[2] => Array(
[id] => 3 [0] => 3
[top] => gall [1] => gall)
)

$target = // subarray having [id] => 2
```

after selecting the target, I suppose the prodedure is like this:

```
unset($rows[$target]);
$rows = $target + $rows;
```

so problem is to select the target subarray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an array of specific "key" in multidimensional array without looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994497/how-to-get-an-array-of-specific-key-in-multidimensional-array-without-looping)

Comment: maybe - using array_column and foreach loop, but I hope there is a way without loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to achieve this. The second argument allows you to provide user-defined sorting function and you can find your expected element there.

```
$id = 2;

$rows = array(
  0 => array(
    "id" => 1,
    "test" => 'test 0'
  ),
  1 => array(
    "id" => 2,
    "test" => 'test 1'
  ),
  2 => array(
    "id" => 3,
    "test" => 'test 2'
  )
);

$clonedRows = array_merge($rows);

usort($clonedRows, function ($a, $b) use ($id) {
  if ($a["id"] === $id) return -1;  
  return 1;
});

var_dump($clonedRows);
var_dump($rows);
```